# Apache POI apply foating point format only if Number is decimal

Tags: java, apache-poi

Currently I'm using the format "#,##0.00" for all the Number type values retrieved from oracle DB to be saved in an excel file, but I don't want to save all values with a floating point if they don't have it on DB

For example

```
12 should be 12
12.1 should be 12.10
12.123 should be 12.12
```

Comment: Then do using data format "General". Or you would need set the special data format "0" to cells which contain integers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no special number format is set for the cell, then number format "General" is used. That will show 12 or 12.1 or 12.123. So to get what you want two different number formats ("0" (or "#,##0" if thousands separator shall be used) for integers and "#,##0.00" for decimals) are needed.

So main question is how to determine whether a number is integer or decimal. Following code does this task using the methods of `Number`. If number's integer value is equal to number's decimal value, then number is integer.

It creates a sheet showing 12 in `A1`, 12.10 in `A2` and 12.12 in `A3`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreateExcelDifferentNumberformats {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  
  // Create CellStyles
  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle integerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  //integerCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0"));
  integerCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0"));
  CellStyle decimalCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  decimalCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.00"));
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

  List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
  numbers.add(12); numbers.add(12.1); numbers.add(12.123);

  int r = 0;
  for (Number number : numbers) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r++); 
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0); 
   cell.setCellValue(number.doubleValue());
   if (number.intValue() == number.doubleValue()) {
    cell.setCellStyle(integerCellStyle);
   } else {
    cell.setCellStyle(decimalCellStyle);   
   }
  } 

  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelDifferentNumberformats.xls");
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelDifferentNumberformats.xlsx");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```